# Hadoop Spark: How to make distinct of elements in JavaRDD?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I want to store distinct of some JavaRDD collection to a file in Spark?

By using distinct() method of RDD, I couldn’t achieve the same.

My guess is RDD treats each element as a individual instance. How can we achieve the distinct in this case.

Following is code snippet, Can anyone please help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Xml Spark Demo");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaSQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext(
            sc);


    // Load a text file and convert each line to a JavaBean.
    JavaRDD<String> dataFromFile = sc.textFile(
            "/home/kedarnath/Rentals/inputData/temp-01.xml").map(
            new ParseAgentFromXml());

    //Need distinct values here
    dataFromFile.distinct().saveAsTextFile("/home/kedarnath/Rentals/testOutputDistinct.txt");

}
```

Thanks in advance,

~Kedar

Comment: Please give more information about what are you referring to with "distinct of some JavaRDD collection to a file".

Comment: Giving an example would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @MikelUrkia for the reply!

Here is Quick Example:

I want to get distinct strings out of a JavaRDD and give them unique number(autoIncrement).

Suppose my JavaRDD contains strings as:
"abc","abc","def","pqr","abc","abc","def","pqr"

I want output as :
1,"abc"
2,"def"
3,"pqr"


Could you please help?

Thanks,
~Kedar

Comment: Please update the question to make easier the understanding of the example. Include what you are looking for and what you actually are getting as an output. That way we will be able to help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this would be the most efficient way of doing it from a performance perspective, but I would try dividing the process in two different steps: dinstinct and mapping to pair. Consider the following example:

```
Original dataset:          Desired output (distinct elements)

Apple                      1, Apple
Tree                       2, Tree
Car                        3, Car
Priest                     4, Priest
Apple                      5, Phone
Tree
Apple
Phone
```

- **Distinct:**

By using the `distinct()` transformation, you would obtain a new RDD dataset with all the distinct element. In this case, it would return something like:

```
Apple
Tree
Car
Priest
Phone
```

- **Map to pair:**

The next step would be to associate a key to every value in the RDD dataset, transforming it into a key-value format. For this, the transformation `mapToPair()` could be used. The output would result on the desired output.

```
1, Apple
2, Tree
3, Car
4, Priest
5, Phone
```

Visit [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html) page to get more information about the different available methods.

Comment: Thanks @Mikel for this reply!

You have understood the exact problem.

The distinct() method that is mentioned above doesn't give the distinct dataset I can see lot repetitive values of same string. I suspect this is because distinct() is treating each string as an individual object. Could you please help me in understanding how exactly we can achieve the distinct here.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it should not happen like that. My guess is that your issue is related to the XML input format. I am saying it from the almost total ignorance, so I would too appreciate any help or suggestion from other people.

Comment: Make sure your class correctly implements equals() and hashCode()